# How to use Jsoup get repeating number?

Tags: java, jsoup

```
 <p class="tl f12">2015-12-06 18:19:42 由<span class="co4">咕咚</span>上传
  <span style="display:none;  margin-top: 5px" class="fr marr15 mc_tips" id="mc_tips_dd5e7f6e-9c02-11e5-a3c1-015176cddf29"><img src="http://static.codoon.com/image/mc/18.gif"></span></p>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="f12 co6" route_id="dd5e7f6e-9c02-11e5-a3c1-015176cddf29"  id="dd5e7f6e-9c02-11e5-a3c1-015176cddf29" >
                <tr>
                    <td width="70" height="42" class="tc">
                        <div class="m_tc" style="width:32px; height:32px;">
                            <img src="http://static.codoon.com/image/app_icon/walk.png" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="100" height="42">
                        <span>距离</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">0.22</span><span class="f12">公里</span>
                    </td>
                    <td width="100" height="42">
                        <span>运动时长</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">00:03</span>   
                    </td>
                    <td width="120" height="42">
                        <span>平均速度</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">3.5</span><span class="f12">公里/小时</span>
                    </td>
                    <td  width="110">                       
                        <span>燃烧</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">14.9</span>大卡
                    </td>
                    <td  class="tl" >

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

i got some data like this,and i want to get data in class="f18 co14 fb f24"
so i use Jsoup as

```
Elements elements = document.select(".f18").select(".co14").select(".fb").select(".f24");
```

then i get them.But when there have some repeating number,such as

```
<p class="tl f12">2015-12-06 18:19:42 由<span class="co4">咕咚</span>上传<span style="display:none;  margin-top: 5px" class="fr marr15 mc_tips" id="mc_tips_dd5e7f6e-9c02-11e5-a3c1-015176cddf29"><img src="http://static.codoon.com/image/mc/18.gif"></span></p>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="f12 co6" route_id="dd5e7f6e-9c02-11e5-a3c1-015176cddf29"  id="dd5e7f6e-9c02-11e5-a3c1-015176cddf29" >
            <tr>
                <td width="70" height="42" class="tc">
                    <div class="m_tc" style="width:32px; height:32px;">
                        <img src="http://static.codoon.com/image/app_icon/walk.png" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="100" height="42">
                    <span>距离</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">0.22</span><span class="f12">公里</span>
                </td>
                <td width="100" height="42">
                    <span>运动时长</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">00:03</span>   
                </td>
                <td width="120" height="42">
                    <span>平均速度</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">3.5</span><span class="f12">公里/小时</span>
                </td>
                <td  width="110">                       
                    <span>燃烧</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">14.9</span>大卡
                </td>
                <td  class="tl" >

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>            
        <p class="tl f12">2015-12-06 17:56:32 由<span class="co4">咕咚</span>上传<span style="display:none;  margin-top: 5px" class="fr marr15 mc_tips" id="mc_tips_a1244433-9bff-11e5-927a-015176b8ab4a"><img src="http://static.codoon.com/image/mc/18.gif"></span></p>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="f12 co6" route_id="a1244433-9bff-11e5-927a-015176b8ab4a"  id="a1244433-9bff-11e5-927a-015176b8ab4a" >
            <tr>
                <td width="70" height="42" class="tc">
                    <div class="m_tc" style="width:32px; height:32px;">
                        <img src="http://static.codoon.com/image/app_icon/walk.png" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="100" height="42">
                    <span>距离</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">0.22</span><span class="f12">公里</span>
                </td>
                <td width="100" height="42">
                    <span>运动时长</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">00:06</span>   
                </td>
                <td width="120" height="42">
                    <span>平均速度</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">2.0</span><span class="f12">公里/小时</span>
                </td>
                <td  width="110">                       
                    <span>燃烧</span><br /><span class="f18 co14 fb f24">13.6</span>大卡
                </td>
                <td  class="tl" >

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

it will not return to me as
 0.22 00:03 3.5  14.9 0.22 00:01 3.3 6.0
it returns  0.22 00:03 3.5  14.9 00:01 3.3 6.0
such as delete the repeating number.so how can i get all of my numbers?

this  is my demo 
[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/FloatingMaple/a6ab3d88dc5717bc42b9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a bug. I created an issue on the JSoup repository [here](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/664).

One way you get all the expected elements would be to not repeat select method calls on the returned elements, but combine them all into one select:

```
Elements els = document.select(".f18.co14.fb.f24");
```

This will contain also the duplicates.

Comment: ok,when i use version 1.8.1,my code can get all numbers.and use your code i can get all numbers in version 1.8.3,Maybe that's a bug.THX~

Answer (score 0):

It might be bug in jsoup version 1.8.2+, switch to version 1.8.1 and you will get output you expect.

Comment: THX, use 1.8.1 really can solve this problem. And use this code                    Elements els = document.select(".f18.co14.fb.f24");  can get all numbers in 1.8.3.