# jSoup: Am not being able to correctly parse two consecutive table cells with identical values?

Tags: jsoup

My Table (shortened and formatted for better viewability ) :

```
String htmlStr = 
"<table class="xt">
  <tbody>
   <tr><th class="bg-warning" colspan="3">-</th></tr>
   <tr><th class="bg-warning">2014-08-29</th><td>0</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>"
```

My code:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlStr);
xt = doc.select("table.xt").first();
thCols = xt.select("tr").eq(1).select("th").size();
tdCols = xt.select("tr").eq(1).select("td").size();
```

Outcome

```
System.out.println(thCols); // prints 1
System.out.println(tdCols); // prints 2 - whereas I am expecting 3
```

Why would this be happening? I did my searches - but the best I could find were comments on how jSoup expects properly constructed HTML5. However, the table above does seem to be compliant, unless I have missed something badly. What else could be the reason?

Comment: ...`<td>0.00</td</tr>` seems not well formatted. Is that your intention?

Comment: Oh - oops! That happened while shortening the table content for better presentation. I have edited the text. I have also rechecked the source - the table html is properly formed there without the above typo. Thank you for the pointer @luksch

Comment: Following the solution contained in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985791/why-jsoup-cannot-select-td-element works - but I am not sure if that is the most optimal way. Grateful for any further suggestions

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117769/how-to-use-jsoup-get-repeating-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest Jsoup 1.8.3, introduced in version Jsoup 1.8.2. If you switch back to 1.8.1 it should work as expected. Another solution would be to create a single selector for the number of tds:

```
String htmlStr = ""
        +"<table class=\"xt\">"
        +"  <tbody>"
        +"   <tr><th class=\"bg-warning\" colspan=\"3\">-</th></tr>"
        +"   <tr><th class=\"bg-warning\">2014-08-29</th><td>0</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td></tr>"
        +"  </tbody>"
        +"</table>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlStr);
Element xt = doc.select("table.xt").first();
int thCols = xt.select("tr").eq(1).select("th").size();
int tdCols = xt.select("tr").eq(1).select("td").size();
int tdCols2 = xt.select("tr:eq(1)>td").size();

System.out.println(thCols); // prints 1
System.out.println(tdCols); // prints 2 - whereas I am expecting 3
System.out.println(tdCols2); // prints 3 as expected
```

This may be the same bug as described [here](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/664)

Comment: Thank you so much @luksch - downgrading to 1.8.1 solved the above and related problems (even traversing the table was getting stuck due to the index issue)